# Java command not found for SBT

Tags: java, dockerfile, sbt

I am working on a docker image which I need to install sbt1.8.2. I downloaded the sbt1.8.2.zip file and unzip it, however while checking the version of sbt using sbtVersion, java is missing even though I declared the JAVA_HOME.

This is my sample dockerfile:

```
ENV SBT_VERSION=1.8.2
ENV JAVA_VERSION=1.8.0_60
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk${JAVA_VERSION}/jre/

# Install SBT 
RUN curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip download/internal/url/sbt-1.8.2.zip
RUN unzip -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip -d /opt/
CMD /opt/sbt/bin/sbt run \ 
  sbt sbtVersion
```

This is my sample bats file for testing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats
load $(pwd)/helpers/sdp-helper.bash

@test "SBT Version" {
  EXPVER="1.8.2"
  run ${dockerRun} bash -c "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre /opt/sbt/bin/sbt sbtVersion"

  sdp::outCmd2Tap
  
  [[ ${status} -eq 0 ]]
  [[ ${lines[0]} =~ "${EXPVER}" ]]
}
```

Error:

```
/opt/sbt/bin/sbt: line 460: java: command not found
copying runtime jar...
mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory
/opt/sbt/bin/sbt: line 467: java: command not found
/opt/sbt/bin/sbt: line 229: exec: java: not found
```

Comment: My guess would be that your Java installation’s `bin` directory is not in the `PATH`.

Comment: Hi @TimMoore, do you mean i need to create an ENV PATH for java bin?

Comment: based on the error messages, yes

Comment: Thanks @TimMoore I have re-constructed my dockerfile and it seems the problem is on environment variables :)